# Error en el el archivo gradle

Tags: flutter

[image: El error aparece bajo la letra G*]

Hola a todooss!!
he estado creando una pequeña app pero me aparece este error en el archivo gradle. Sin embargo, pese a ello puedo correr la aplicacion y compila sin ningun problema.
antes del error habia registrado la app en firebase, agregué los plugings en este mismo archivo y  la libreria de firebase messaging aunque no se si realmente sea de alli el problema. de antemanoo gracias!

Comment: Buscando un poco he encontrado esta `solución`: consiste en sustituir `throw new GradleException(...)` por `throw new FileNotFoundException(...)`; la encontré en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211963/gradleexception-is-showing-red-is-that-any-error-or-not

Comment: Si es un proyecto de Flutter, según veo por la etiqueta, los archivos de gradle siempre marcan errores, pero no te preocupes por ellos. No son ciertos.